Is email the standard method to transfer disclosures to your attorney?
All of my document and disclosure exchange with my attorney has been via email (google gmail).
I had worked with another patent attorney a year a ago where I upload documents via a google shared folder.
Other questions:

How do attorneys ensure that the documents shared with them via email remain safe and confidential?
Are there any special protocols?


As George White states, email attachments and shared folders are fine so long as the sharing is limited to just the client and lawyer. Personally, for sensitive communications such as tax documents, I use compressed, encrypted folders. These are easy to do on MacOS and I assume similarly available on Windows computers. I then communicate the encryption password with the recipient over the phone.

Using email and shared folders is common. You could encrypt or lock documents but I don’t think that is done very frequently.
Before retiring as a patent agent I did have one client who didn’t trust Google and insisted on corresponding via Yahoo Mail.
